# Is there a reason why my wordpress PHP page isn't loading into my PHP template

Tags: php, jquery, javascript, advanced-custom-fields

Please bear with me because I am new to utilizing Wordpress PHP this way. I have the following script:

```
<div id="content">
<?php
    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if( have_rows('repeat_field') ):
        $i = 0;

        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('repeat_field') ) : the_row();
            $i++;

            // display a sub field value
            if (!empty(get_sub_field('feature_image_post'))) {

                echo '<a href="';
                the_sub_field('restaurant_article_link'); 
                echo '">';
            } 
            if( $i >= 78 ) {
                break;
            }            
        endwhile;
    else :
        // no rows found
    endif;
    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="loading-image" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="part2"></div>
    <script>

        var w = $(window);
        window.onscroll = function(ev) {
            if ($(document).height() - w.height() == w.scrollTop()) {

                $('#loading-image').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/post-2.php",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result){
                      $("#part2").html(result);
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                      $('#loading-image').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    </script>
```

The the Php page that I am trying to load pretty much contains the same code . It just stops after loading 200 fields.

```
<?php
    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if( have_rows('repeat_field') ):
        $i = 0;
        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('repeat_field') ) : the_row();
            $i++;
            // display a sub field value
            if (!empty(get_sub_field('feature_image_post'))) {
                echo '<a href="';
                the_sub_field('restaurant_article_link'); 
                echo '">';
            } 
            if( $i >= 200 ){
              break;
            }            

        endwhile;
    else :
        // no rows found
    endif;
?>
```

I don't know why the php page (post-2.php) is not loading. The strange thing is that when I replace `<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/post-2.php` with a test html page `<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/test.html` The test page (test.html) loads. 
I have to say that I looked on in my console using the console tab of my browser added `console.log();` to view any errors and I'm not getting any errors. I also looked in my networked tag to ensure that post-2.php loaded properly and I'm not getting errors. My goal is to find out why my PHP page isn't loading

***** Update *****
I'm being told to use $post_id but I've never used it. Does anyone have a working example of this? Would it be similar to `if( have_rows('repeat_field', $post_id) ):` or `if( have_rows('repeat_field', 55612) ):` ?

Comment: Put some thing in else part so that you could get some result when you have no rows to return.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used ACF before but i suspect your `post-2.php` lacks `$post_id`  as in `have_rows($field_name, $post_id)`([see](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/)). If you are using ajax there is no way that your ajax function know the page you are on and what post you are seeking so you better use `$post_id` to tell  ajax function which post data you want.

Correct way of using ajax in `wordpress` is directing ajax request to `ajaxurl = admin_url().'admin-ajax.php'`. It is better to  `wp_localize_script` but can do like this  `<div id="part2" data-url="<?php echo admin_url().'admin-ajax.php'; ?>"></div>` and the `ajaxurl = $('#part2').data('url);`

You can use something like this

```
 $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                cache: false,

                type : 'post',
                data : {
                   action: 'load_post_acf' // This will be used in hook
                 },

                success: function(result){
                   $("#part2").html(result);
                   $('#loading-image').hide();
                },

           });
```

Ajax function for `post-2.php` you can do something like ..

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_post_acf','your_ajax_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_load_post_acf','your_ajax_function');

function your_ajax_function(){
  global $post;
  if( have_rows('repeat_field',$post->ID) ):
    // do something
  else:
   echo '<h4>No rows found.</h4>'; //do something else
  endif;


}
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. So what is `admin-ajax.php`? The URL Page that I am going to is named `post-2.php` Are you saying that in my template page  my ajax call should be similar to the following `ajaxurl = admin_url().'admin-ajax.php'` or `ajaxurl = admin_url().'post-2.php'`?

Comment: `ajax-admin.php`  is the core file of wordpress do some research a  `ajaxurl`  should be `admin_url().'admin-ajax.php'` and your `post-2.php` should be included in themes `functions.php` file.

Comment: @ Bikash Waiba I tried your code example and it isn't working for me. I understand that Post Id should work but when I implemented your code example it didn't work for me `$post_id`

Comment: There is no `global $post_id`, you need to pass post ID with data, the same way you pass action.

Comment: @Milo do you mean I need to exactly write `global $post_id;` at the begining of my code? For example `  global $post_id;
  if( have_rows('repeat_field',$post_id) ):`

Comment: `global $post;` and `$post_id = $post->ID;` without that you have no $post_id variable.